# Substring index with dynamic value and 1 column result

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-workbench, group-concat

I use mysql and have a table the name is table *tag* with column value like this

```
 code     tag_customer
 TG001     1,2,3
 TG002     2,3,4,5
```

and also i have master_tag table of tag name like this

```
id    value
1     New
2     Active
3     Gold
4     Silver
5     Bronze
```

I would like to select the data but with the value name of this tag :

```
code     tag_value
TG001    New,Active,gold
TG002    Active,Gold,Silver,Bronze
```

I tried substring index but its show results in a different column and also still need to manual declaration how many lop the substring index need to declare meanwhile the value of tag is dynamic not static

Comment: Your problem is an inappropriate data model. You must not store multiple IDs in a string. That violates database normalization and prevents the DBMS to ensure data consistency. Make this a table consisting of one column for the code and one for a single tag.

Comment: Yes, correct. there are situations that are an old design that I realized to normalize it. thank you for your reminder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the tables, group by `code` an use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to collect the tag values:

```
SELECT t.code,
       GROUP_CONCAT(m.value ORDER BY m.id) tag_value
FROM tag t INNER JOIN master_tag m
ON FIND_IN_SET(m.id, t.tag_customer)
GROUP BY t.code;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=153e0a1d4f585db59980abf4572d1aa6).